# where is the includes and headers during compilation?

Tags: gcc, compilation

I know the includes and headers will be copied into source file during preprocessor process.

I use gcc to compile the file.

source file(.c file):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    printf("Hello World!!!");
    return 0;
}
```

I can see them in ".i" file

```
# 1 "test.c"
# 1 "<built-in>"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "/usr/include/stdc-predef.h" 1 3 4
# 1 "<command-line>" 2
# 1 "test.c"
# 1 "/usr/include/stdio.h" 1 3 4
# 27 "/usr/include/stdio.h" 3 4
# 1 "/usr/include/features.h" 1 3 4
# 367 "/usr/include/features.h" 3 4
# 1 "/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/cdefs.h" 1 3 4
# 410 "/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/cdefs.h" 3 4
# 1 "/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/wordsize.h" 1 3 4
# 411 "/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/cdefs.h" 2 3 4
# 368 "/usr/include/features.h" 2 3 4
# 391 "/usr/include/features.h" 3 4
# 1 "/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/gnu/stubs.h" 1 3 4
# 10 "/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/gnu/stubs.h" 3 4
# 1 "/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/gnu/stubs-64.h" 1 3 4
# 11 "/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/gnu/stubs.h" 2 3 4
# 392 "/usr/include/features.h" 2 3 4
# 28 "/usr/include/stdio.h" 2 3 4
.......
```

However, after generating the assembly file (.s), it seems all of them are gone.

```
    .file   "test.c"
    .section    .rodata
.LC0:
    .string "Hello World!!!"
    .text
    .globl  main
    .type   main, @function
main:
.LFB0:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    movl    $.LC0, %edi
    movl    $0, %eax
    call    printf
    movl    $0, %eax
    popq    %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE0:
    .size   main, .-main
    .ident  "GCC: (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 5.4.0 20160609"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

My questions are:

1. In the assembly file, where is the include stdio.h I added in the source code?
2. What is the role of the includes and headers during compilation? How do they effect the compile process?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Header files in C and C++ provide the compiler with information
that it requires in order to parse the source files in which you
`#include` them. You `#include` them in a source file 
to enable the compiler to do that. Having parsed a source
file, and all the `#include`-ed header files, the compiler
is able to generate an object code file that is capable of
being linked together with others in an executable. That linking
is done by your [linker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linker_(computing))

It is quite unnecessary for all of the
information that *enables* the compiler to parse the source
file to be copied in any form into the object file. Once it
has served the purpose of parsing, the great majority of
it is typically of no further use. A recipe enables you to cook a dish. When
you have cooked the dish, you don't expect to find the recipe *in it*.

If you generate and examine the assembly code that the compiler
produces from some input source file, what you are looking at is
an assembly language translation of the *object file* that the
compiler will produce from the same input. Any information that
is unnecessary and absent in the object code is likewise unnecessary
and absent in the assembly code.

Much of the information in a typical header file defines,
in code, the programming interfaces of software facilities that your own code 
will make use of, but which are already compiled in some external library that your own object
code will need to be linked with. This information enables the
compiler to generate object code the can be linked with that
external library in the intended and correct way.

In your assembly listing, for instance,  you can see the program initializing registers
to make a call to `printf` As you know, that is a Standard C function, implemented
in the C runtime library that your program will be linked with,
whose interface is specified by a function declaration in `<stdio.h>`, which you `#included`.
The compiler needed `<stdio.h>` only to verify that setting up the `printf`
call in this way conforms with the calling procedure that `printf` expects
in the C runtime library. Well, in your object code that `printf` call *is*
set up exactly as you see in the assembly, and `<stdio.h>` was waste material once that was done.

You may be further enlightened by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6264256/1362568)